How do I fix the layout issues on "Circle" and "Trapezoid" pages?
These pages have a broken and unexpected layout
I have tried using columnspan, rowspan, .gridrowconfigure() and .gridcolumnconfigure() to no avail.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font
import math
import cmath

FONT40 = ('Roboto', 40)
FONT20 = ('Roboto', 20)
FONT24 = ('Roboto', 24)
FONT16 = ('Roboto', 16)
BGCOLOR = '#545454'
BTNCOLOR = '#909090'
pi = (3.14)


root = tk.Tk() #application window
root.geometry("690x938")
root.title("Calculator Project (Beta 0.1)")
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.config(background="#545454")

root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)



page1 = tk.Frame(root, background=BGCOLOR) 
page2 = tk.Frame(root, background=BGCOLOR)
page3 = tk.Frame(root, background=BGCOLOR)
page4 = tk.Frame(root, background=BGCOLOR)

page1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")
page2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")
page3.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")
page4.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")

for page in (page1, page2, page3, page4):
    page.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    page.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)


#PAGE 1 == MAIN PAGE
frame1 = tk.Frame(page1, bg=BGCOLOR)
frame1.pack(expand=1) #center frame


ttl1M = tk.Label(frame1, text="Calculator", font=FONT20, bg=BGCOLOR)
ttl1M.pack(pady=20)

quadratics_btn = tk.Button(frame1, text="Quadratics Calculator", font=FONT20, command=lambda: page2.tkraise(), bg=BTNCOLOR)
quadratics_btn.pack(pady=10)

simple_geometry_btn = tk.Button(frame1, text="Geometry General", font=FONT20, command=lambda: page3.tkraise(), bg=BTNCOLOR)
simple_geometry_btn.pack(pady=10)

notYetImplemented_btn = tk.Button(frame1, text="Not Yet Implemented", font=FONT20, command=lambda: page4.tkraise(), bg=BTNCOLOR)
notYetImplemented_btn.pack(pady=10)

#PAGE2 == QUADRATICS CALCULATOR
frame2 = tk.Frame(page2, bg=BGCOLOR)
frame2.pack(expand=1)


qdrtcs = tk.Label(frame2, text="Quadratic Page", font=FONT20, bg=BGCOLOR)
qdrtcs.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, pady=20)

#spinboxes for A/B/C start
quadA = tk.Spinbox(frame2, width=5, font=FONT24)
quadA.grid(pady=30, row=1, column=0, columnspan=1)

quadB = tk.Spinbox(frame2, width=5, font=FONT24)
quadB.grid(pady=30, row=1, column=1, columnspan=1)

quadC = tk.Spinbox(frame2, width=5, font=FONT24)
quadC.grid(pady=30, row=1, column=2, columnspan=1)

ans_quadratic = tk.Label(frame2, font=FONT16, text='', bg=BGCOLOR)
ans_quadratic.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=10, columnspan=1)

#Calculation function - quadratics
def quadratic_calculation():
    #gets values from the user (spinboxes)
    valueA = quadA.get()
    valueB = quadB.get()
    valueC = quadC.get()

    try:
          valueA = float(valueA)
          valueB = float(valueB)
          valueC = float(valueC)
    except ValueError:
          print("invalid input, must be an integer(number)")
          return

    discriminant = pow(valueB, 2) - (4*valueA*valueC)

    if discriminant > 0 :

            POSans1 = (-valueB + math.sqrt(discriminant)) / 2*valueA
            POSans2 = (-valueB - math.sqrt(discriminant)) / 2*valueA

            absolute_answer = f"x₁ = {round(POSans1, 2)}" + " , " + f"x₂ = {round(POSans2, 2)}"
            

    elif discriminant == 0:

            EQans1 = (-valueB + math.sqrt(discriminant)) / 2*valueA
            absolute_answer = f"x = {round(EQans1, 2)}"
            

    else:
            NEG_ans1 = (-valueB + cmath.sqrt(discriminant))/ (2*valueA)
            NEG_ans2 = (-valueB - cmath.sqrt(discriminant))/ (2*valueA)

            absolute_answer = f"x₁ = {round(NEG_ans1.real, 2)} + {round(NEG_ans1.imag, 2)}i, x₂ = {round(NEG_ans2.real, 2)} + {round(NEG_ans1.imag, 2)}i"

    ans_quadratic.config(text=absolute_answer)    


get_quadratic_values = tk.Button(frame2, font=FONT20, command=quadratic_calculation, text="Calculate", bg=BTNCOLOR).grid(row=3, column=1, pady=30)    

#Go back button for quadratic page
back_btn = tk.Button(frame2, text="Go back", font=FONT20, command=lambda: page1.tkraise(), bg=BTNCOLOR)
back_btn.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=3)

#Page3 Simple Geometry, not yet implemented

geometrySubPage1 = tk.Frame(root, background=BGCOLOR)
geometrySubPage2 = tk.Frame(root, background=BGCOLOR)
geometrySubPage3 = tk.Frame(root, background=BGCOLOR)

geometrySubPage1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")
geometrySubPage2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")
geometrySubPage3.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")

for subPage1 in (geometrySubPage1, geometrySubPage2, geometrySubPage3):
    subPage1.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    subPage1.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

frame3 = tk.Frame(page3, bg=BGCOLOR)
frame3.pack(expand=1) #center the frame

nyi1 = tk.Label(frame3, text="Simple Geometry (not yet fully implemented)", font=FONT20, bg="#545454")
nyi1.grid(pady=20)

#geometry buttons navigation
triangleBTN = tk.Button(frame3, text="Calculate Triangles", font=FONT24, bg=BTNCOLOR, command=lambda: geometrySubPage1.tkraise())
triangleBTN.grid(pady=20)

CircleBTN = tk.Button(frame3, text="Calculate Circles", font=FONT24, bg=BTNCOLOR, command=lambda: geometrySubPage2.tkraise())
CircleBTN.grid(pady=20)

trapBTN = tk.Button(frame3, text="Calculate Trapezoids", font=FONT24, bg=BTNCOLOR, command=lambda: geometrySubPage3.tkraise())
trapBTN.grid(pady=20)

back_btn = tk.Button(frame3, text="Go back", font=FONT20, command=lambda: page1.tkraise(), bg=BTNCOLOR)
back_btn.grid(pady=20)

#geometry sub page 1
subFrame1 = tk.Frame(geometrySubPage1, bg=BGCOLOR)
subFrame1.pack(expand=1)

SubGeoLabel = tk.Label(subFrame1, text="triangle area calculator", font=FONT40, bg=BGCOLOR)
SubGeoLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="wen", pady=40, columnspan=2)

#height
tPrompt1 = tk.Label(subFrame1, text="Input Height: ", font=FONT16, bg=BGCOLOR)
tPrompt1.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10, columnspan=1)

tHeight = tk.Spinbox(subFrame1, from_=0, to=999, font=FONT16, width=5)
tHeight.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=1)
#height
tPrompt2 = tk.Label(subFrame1, text="Input Base: ", font=FONT16, bg=BGCOLOR)
tPrompt2.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=10, columnspan=1)

tBase = tk.Spinbox(subFrame1, from_=0, to=999, font=FONT16, width=5)
tBase.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=1)

triangle_answer_label = tk.Label(subFrame1, text='', font=FONT24, bg=BGCOLOR)
triangle_answer_label.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=30, columnspan=2)

#triangle calculations
def triangle_calc():
    triangle_height = tHeight.get()
    triangle_base = tBase.get()
    
    try:
        triangle_height = float(triangle_height)
        triangle_base = float(triangle_base)
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input type, must be an interger(number)")
        return
    
    tAns = (1/2) * triangle_base * triangle_height
    
    triangle_answer_label.config(text=f"Triangle area = {tAns}")
    
    

#submit button
tAnswer = tk.Button(subFrame1, text="Calculate", font=FONT24, command=triangle_calc, bg=BTNCOLOR).grid(row=4, column=0, pady=30, columnspan=2)

#back button
back_btn = tk.Button(subFrame1, text="Go back", font=FONT20, command=lambda: page3.tkraise(), bg=BTNCOLOR)
back_btn.grid(pady=20, columnspan=2)

#circle subpage 2

CircleSubPage1 = tk.Frame(root, background=BGCOLOR) #Circle selection screen
CircleSubPage2 = tk.Frame(root, background=BGCOLOR) #Circle Area Calculator page
CircleSubPage3 = tk.Frame(root, background=BGCOLOR) #Circle Circumference Calculator Page

CircleSubPage1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")
CircleSubPage2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")
CircleSubPage3.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")

for subPage2 in (CircleSubPage1, CircleSubPage2, CircleSubPage3):
    subPage2.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    subPage2.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


CircleFrame1 = tk.Frame(CircleSubPage1, bg=BGCOLOR)
CircleFrame1.pack(expand=1)


CircleTitleLabel = tk.Label(geometrySubPage2, bg=BGCOLOR, font=FONT24, text='Circle Calculators')
CircleTitleLabel.grid(pady=20, row=0, column=0)

circle_area_btn = tk.Button(geometrySubPage2, text="Area", font=FONT24, command=lambda: CircleSubPage2.tkraise(), bg=BTNCOLOR)
circle_area_btn.grid(pady=20, row=1, column=0)

circle_circumference_btn = tk.Button(geometrySubPage2, text="Circumference", font=FONT24, command=lambda: CircleSubPage3.tkraise(), bg=BTNCOLOR)
circle_circumference_btn.grid(pady=20, row=2, column=0)

                #   I cannot figure out how to fix this darn layout.
                #   It's so annoying that there's this massive space between 
                #   the title and the buttons >:(

#Area of Circle page

CircleFrame2 = tk.Frame(CircleSubPage2, bg=BGCOLOR)
CircleFrame2.pack(expand=1)

    #Circle area page title
circle_area_label = tk.Label(CircleFrame2, text="Circle Area Calculator", font=FONT24, bg=BGCOLOR)
circle_area_label.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=20, columnspan=3)
    #Circle spinbox input prompt
RadPromptQ = tk.Label(CircleFrame2, text="Input Radius: ", font=FONT16, bg=BGCOLOR)
RadPromptQ.grid(pady=20, row=1, column=0, padx=(10,5))

RadPrompt = tk.Spinbox(CircleFrame2, font=FONT16, bg=BGCOLOR, width=10)
RadPrompt.grid(pady=20, row=1, column=1, padx=(5,10), columnspan=3)

C_area_ans_label = tk.Label(CircleFrame2, text='', font=FONT20, bg=BGCOLOR)
C_area_ans_label.grid(pady=20, column=0, row=3, columnspan=3)
    
    #Circle area process
def cAreaCalc():
     C_rad = RadPrompt.get()

     try:
          C_rad = float(C_rad)
     except ValueError:
          print("Invalid input type, must be an interger(number)")
          return
     
     c_area = pi*C_rad**2

     C_area_ans_label.config(text=f"The area of the circle is: {round(c_area, 2)}m²")

c_area_smt_btn = tk.Button(CircleFrame2, text='Submit', font=FONT24, bg=BTNCOLOR, command=cAreaCalc)
c_area_smt_btn.grid(pady=20, column=0, row=4, columnspan=3)
    #Back Button for Circle area page
back_btn = tk.Button(CircleFrame2, text="Go back", font=FONT20, command=lambda: geometrySubPage2.tkraise(), bg=BTNCOLOR)
back_btn.grid(pady=20, row=5, column=0, columnspan=3)
########

# Circumference of circle page
CircleFrame3 = tk.Frame(CircleSubPage3, bg=BGCOLOR)
CircleFrame3.pack(expand=1)

Circumference_title_label = tk.Label(CircleFrame3, text="Circumference Calculator", font=FONT40, bg=BGCOLOR)
Circumference_title_label.grid(pady=20, row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

circum_label = tk.Label(CircleFrame3, text="input circle radius: ", bg=BGCOLOR, font=FONT24)
circum_label.grid(pady=20, row=1, column=0, columnspan=1)

circum_radius = tk.Spinbox(CircleFrame3, font=FONT20, width=5)
circum_radius.grid(pady=20, row=1, column=1, columnspan=2)

circum_ans_label = tk.Label(CircleFrame3, text='', font=24, fg="#ffffff", bg=BGCOLOR)
circum_ans_label.grid(pady=20, row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)
#Circumference calculation
def circumference_calculate():
     
     circumference_rad = circum_radius.get()
     
     try:
          
          circumference_rad = float(circumference_rad)

     except ValueError:
          print("Invalid input type, must be an interger(number)")
          return
     
     circumference = 2 * pi * circumference_rad

     circum_ans_label.config(text=f"The circumference is: {round(circumference, 2)}")
#######
circum_sbmt_btn = tk.Button(CircleFrame3, text="Calculate", font=FONT24, bg=BTNCOLOR, command=circumference_calculate)
circum_sbmt_btn.grid(pady=20, row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)

back_btn = tk.Button(CircleFrame3, text="Go back", font=FONT20, command=lambda: page3.tkraise(), bg=BTNCOLOR)
back_btn.grid(pady=20, row=4, column=0, columnspan=2)
###########
back_btn = tk.Button(geometrySubPage2, text="Go back", font=FONT20, command=lambda: page3.tkraise(), bg=BTNCOLOR)
back_btn.grid(pady=20, row=4, column=0)

#Trapezoid Subpage

trap_title_label = tk.Label(geometrySubPage3, text="Trapezoid Area Calculator", bg=BGCOLOR, font=FONT24)
trap_title_label.grid(pady=20, row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

trap_base = tk.Label(geometrySubPage3, text="input trapezoid base: ", bg=BGCOLOR, font=FONT24)
trap_base.grid(pady=20, row=1, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky='e')

trap_base_prompt = tk.Spinbox(geometrySubPage3, font=FONT20, width=5)
trap_base_prompt.grid(pady=20, row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky='w')

trap_height = tk.Label(geometrySubPage3, text="input trapezoid height: ", bg=BGCOLOR, font=FONT24)
trap_height.grid(pady=20, row=2, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky='e')

trap_height_prompt = tk.Spinbox(geometrySubPage3, font=FONT20, width=5)
trap_height_prompt.grid(pady=20, row=2, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky='w')

back_btn_trap = tk.Button(geometrySubPage3, text="Go back", font=FONT20, command=lambda: page3.tkraise(), bg=BTNCOLOR)
back_btn_trap.grid(pady=20, row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)

#Page4 - Not yet implemented

frame4 = tk.Frame(page4, bg=BGCOLOR)
frame4.pack(expand=1) #center the frame

nyi2 = tk.Label(frame4, text="Under further construction", font=FONT20, bg="#545454")
nyi2.pack(pady=20)

#go back button

back_btn = tk.Button(frame4, text="Go back", font=FONT20, command=lambda: page1.tkraise(), bg=BTNCOLOR)
back_btn.pack()

page1.tkraise()
root.mainloop()

This is a personal project of mine. Sorry for the long code. I know my coding style and comments are garbage compared to what some of you senior developers have, but I'm learning. Any other suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you

The best way to learn when you have a bug like this is to make a [mre]. That way it's much easier to see what is going on as you can focus only on the important parts of the code. That is partially why on StackOverflow we ask for a [mre] when posting a question. Right now, not a lot of people will be interested in reading+understanding all of the code in order to find the root cause of the bug as it's too much code

What is the expected layout? Specify the issues you want to fix.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Your design is hard to trace and I would suggest to embed related stuff in Frame subclass as it is much easier to layout the design.
